# Show some data from datatable at a time (Not paging)

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

I have a datatable in which I have **4 rows coming** but

> I want to show only 2 data at time. and after of 3 seconds, will show another two

Here is my code:-

```
protected void GetDatafortable1()
{
    lblpltfrm_Number.Text = "PlatForm 1";
    list.InnerHtml = "";
    dv_FromStop.InnerHtml = "";
    Dv_ToStop.InnerHtml = "";
    dv_Time.InnerHtml = "";
    dv_status.InnerHtml = "";
    // int svalue = Convert.ToInt32(Session["ReloadValue"]);
    DataTable obj_Dt = new DataTable();
    OracleConnection obj_Connection = new OracleConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OracleConn"].ToString());

    string Query = "Select x.SR_NO,x.FROM_STOP,x.TO_STOP,x.ORIGIN_STOP_TIME from XXACL_PN_BUS_TIMETABLE x WHERE SCREEN_NUMBER=1";
    using (OracleCommand obj_Command = new OracleCommand(Query))
    {
        OracleDataAdapter obj_Adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(obj_Command);
        obj_Command.Connection = obj_Connection;
        obj_Adapter.SelectCommand = obj_Command;
        obj_Adapter.Fill(obj_Dt);
        int Count = obj_Dt.Rows.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < obj_Dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {

            list.InnerHtml = list.InnerHtml + "<br />" +
                 obj_Dt.Rows[i]["SR_NO"];
            dv_FromStop.InnerHtml = dv_FromStop.InnerHtml + "<br />" +
                obj_Dt.Rows[i]["FROM_STOP"];
            Dv_ToStop.InnerHtml = Dv_ToStop.InnerHtml + "<br />" +
                obj_Dt.Rows[i]["TO_STOP"];
            dv_Time.InnerHtml = dv_Time.InnerHtml + "<br />" +
                obj_Dt.Rows[i]["ORIGIN_STOP_TIME"];
        }

        //Data1Arrived = true;
    }
}
```

**NOTE** Timing is being handled by `Timer`

```
<asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" OnTick="Timer1_Tick" Interval="3000" Enabled="true" />
```

**HTML**

```
<table style="width: 100%; height: 550px; text-align: center; border-collapse: collapse;"
            runat="server" id="tbl1Details">
            <colgroup>
                <col width="5%" />
                <col width="45%" />
            </colgroup>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4" style="height: 10px; border: 1px solid black;">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblpltfrm_Number" Style="height: 10px; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold;"
                        runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="height: 10px; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold; border: 1px solid black;">
                    SR.no
                </td>
                <td style="height: 10px; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold; border: 1px solid black;">
                    Stop
                </td>
                <td style="height: 10px; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold; border: 1px solid black;">
                    Time
                </td>
                <td style="height: 10px; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold; border: 1px solid black;">
                    Status
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="tTime" runat="server" style="vertical-align: top; border: 1px solid black;">
                    <div id="list" runat="server" style="font-size: 25px;">
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <table style="width: 100%; height: 551px; border-collapse: collapse;">
                        <colgroup>
                            <col width="50%" />
                            <col width="50%" />
                        </colgroup>
                        <tr style="vertical-align: top;">
                            <td style="vertical-align: top; border: 0 solid black; text-align: left;">
                                <div id="dv_FromStop" runat="server" style="font-size: 25px;">
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td style="vertical-align: top; border: 0 solid black; text-align: left;">
                                <div id="Dv_ToStop" runat="server" style="font-size: 25px;">
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
                <td style="vertical-align: top; border: 1px solid black;">
                    <div id="dv_Time" runat="server" style="font-size: 25px;">
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td style="vertical-align: top; border: 1px solid black;">
                    <div id="dv_status" runat="server" style="font-size: 25px; vertical-align: top;">
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

**MY EARLIER CODE WHICH WAS WORKING,  BUT I DON'T WANT TO USE [SESSION] NOW**

```
using (OracleCommand obj_Command = new OracleCommand(Query))
    {
        OracleDataAdapter obj_Adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(obj_Command);
        obj_Command.Connection = obj_Connection;
        obj_Adapter.SelectCommand = obj_Command;
        obj_Adapter.Fill(obj_Dt);
        int Count = obj_Dt.Rows.Count;
        for (int i = 0; i < obj_Dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (i < 2)
            {
                list.InnerHtml = list.InnerHtml + "<br />" +
                     obj_Dt.Rows[i]["SR_NO"];
                dv_FromStop.InnerHtml = dv_FromStop.InnerHtml + "<br />" +
                    obj_Dt.Rows[i]["FROM_STOP"];
                Dv_ToStop.InnerHtml = Dv_ToStop.InnerHtml + "<br />" +
                    obj_Dt.Rows[i]["TO_STOP"];
                dv_Time.InnerHtml = dv_Time.InnerHtml + "<br />" +
                    obj_Dt.Rows[i]["ORIGIN_STOP_TIME"];
            }
            else
            {
                Session["NextPlatForm"] = 1;
                Session["A"] = "PlatForm 1";
                dv2SRNo.InnerHtml = dv2SRNo.InnerHtml + "<br />" +
                 obj_Dt.Rows[i]["SR_NO"];
                dv2From_Stop.InnerHtml = dv2From_Stop.InnerHtml + "<br />" +
                    obj_Dt.Rows[i]["FROM_STOP"];
                dv2ToStop.InnerHtml = dv2ToStop.InnerHtml + "<br />" +
                    obj_Dt.Rows[i]["TO_STOP"];
                dv2Time.InnerHtml = dv2Time.InnerHtml + "<br />" +
                    obj_Dt.Rows[i]["ORIGIN_STOP_TIME"];


            }
        }
    }
```

**II update**

```
private void UpdateHtmlData()
{
    DataTable dt = (DataTable)Session["TimeTable"];
    int index = (int)Session["Index"];
    for (int i = index; i <= index+1 && i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                list.InnerHtml = list.InnerHtml + "<br />" +
                     dt.Rows[i]["SR_NO"];
                dv_FromStop.InnerHtml = dv_FromStop.InnerHtml + "<br />" +
                   dt.Rows[i]["FROM_STOP"];
                Dv_ToStop.InnerHtml = Dv_ToStop.InnerHtml + "<br />" +
                    dt.Rows[i]["TO_STOP"];
                dv_Time.InnerHtml = dv_Time.InnerHtml + "<br />" +
                    dt.Rows[i]["ORIGIN_STOP_TIME"];
            }
    Session["Index"] = index + 2;
}
```

Also see the methods

```
protected void GetDatafortable1()
{
    lblpltfrm_Number.Text = "PlatForm 1";
    list.InnerHtml = "";
    dv_FromStop.InnerHtml = "";
    Dv_ToStop.InnerHtml = "";
    dv_Time.InnerHtml = "";
    dv_status.InnerHtml = "";
    // int svalue = Convert.ToInt32(Session["ReloadValue"]);
    DataTable obj_Dt = new DataTable();
    OracleConnection obj_Connection = new OracleConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OracleConn"].ToString());

    string Query = "Select x.SR_NO,x.FROM_STOP,x.TO_STOP,x.ORIGIN_STOP_TIME from XXACL_PN_BUS_TIMETABLE x WHERE SCREEN_NUMBER=1";
    using (OracleCommand obj_Command = new OracleCommand(Query))
    {
        OracleDataAdapter obj_Adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(obj_Command);
        obj_Command.Connection = obj_Connection;
        obj_Adapter.SelectCommand = obj_Command;
        obj_Adapter.Fill(obj_Dt);

        Session["TimeTable"] = obj_Dt;
        Session["Index"] = 0;
    }
}

protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tbl1Details.Visible = false;
    tbl2Details.Visible = false;
    tbl3Details.Visible = false;

    if (Data1Arrived)
    {
        tbl1Details.Visible = true;
        Data1Arrived = false;
        Data2Arrived = true;
        Data3Arrived = false;
        lblpltfrm_Number.Text = "PlatForm 1";
        GetDatafortable1();
        UpdateHtmlData();
    }}
```

`Page_load`

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        GetDatafortable1();
        GetDatafortable2();
        GetDatafortable3();

        UpdateHtmlData();}
```

Comment: using jquery and ajax, it can simply done

Comment: @AbdurRahim: i want this in code behind.

Comment: If you want to show, 2 data, then you must go client side. So why dont you manipulate from client side? you can query each 3 seconds after

Comment: @AbdurRahim: i cant change my whole logic just only for this. any ways thanks for your suggestion.!!

Comment: your above C# code is in Timer1_Tick?

Comment: @Viru: No, it is not in `Timer1_Tick` I created one function for that

Comment: can you pls post whole code.....whats in Timer_Tick? where the above code is palced?

Comment: I am assuming Timer1_Tick is calling GetDataforTable1, am I correcT?

Comment: @Viru: yes exactly you are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can move the logic to call oracle in separate method and store the resultant datatable in ViewState or Session...Also store index which will indicate number of rows already read...then have a separate method which will update UI on Timer Tick

```
protected void GetDatafortable1()
{
    lblpltfrm_Number.Text = "PlatForm 1";
    list.InnerHtml = "";
    dv_FromStop.InnerHtml = "";
    Dv_ToStop.InnerHtml = "";
    dv_Time.InnerHtml = "";
    dv_status.InnerHtml = "";
    // int svalue = Convert.ToInt32(Session["ReloadValue"]);
    DataTable obj_Dt = new DataTable();
    OracleConnection obj_Connection = new OracleConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OracleConn"].ToString());

    string Query = "Select x.SR_NO,x.FROM_STOP,x.TO_STOP,x.ORIGIN_STOP_TIME from XXACL_PN_BUS_TIMETABLE x WHERE SCREEN_NUMBER=1";
    using (OracleCommand obj_Command = new OracleCommand(Query))
    {
        OracleDataAdapter obj_Adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(obj_Command);
        obj_Command.Connection = obj_Connection;
        obj_Adapter.SelectCommand = obj_Command;
        obj_Adapter.Fill(obj_Dt);
       ViewState["TimeTable"] = obj_Dt;
       ViewState["Index"] = 0; 

        //Data1Arrived = true;
    }
}

private void UpdateHtml()
{
DataTable dt = (DataTable) ViewState["TimeTable"]
int index = (int) ViewState["Index"];
for (int i = index; i <= index+1 && i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {

            list.InnerHtml = list.InnerHtml + "<br />" +
                 dt.Rows[i]["SR_NO"];
            dv_FromStop.InnerHtml = dv_FromStop.InnerHtml + "<br />" +
               dt.Rows[i]["FROM_STOP"];
            Dv_ToStop.InnerHtml = Dv_ToStop.InnerHtml + "<br />" +
                dt.Rows[i]["TO_STOP"];
            dv_Time.InnerHtml = dv_Time.InnerHtml + "<br />" +
                dt.Rows[i]["ORIGIN_STOP_TIME"];
        }

ViewState["Index"] = index + 2;

}

proctected void page_load()
{  
 if(!IsPostBack())
  {
   GetDatafortable1();
   UpdateHtml();
  }
}
 proctected void timer1_tick()
{
UpdateHtml();
}
```

Comment: Yes do not call GetDataforTable1 in timer1_tick...As all your rows are fetched already and saved in ViewState...and also updated code in UpdateHtml method....I guess you faced issue while showing data for row 3 and row 4

Comment: added one more check in for loop in UpdateHtml method....I have not tested it so there might be few bugs but it gives you fair enough idea how you can achieve what you want without much change in your code

Comment: Did you debug and check what is going wrong? whether timer1_tick was calleed?

Comment: then what was the value of index you see when you debug?

Comment: Try changing ViewState to Session state...I think value in ViewState is lost during postback

Comment: Did you change ViewState to Session in GetDatafortable1 method also? I think you have not thats why you see the error

Comment: Yes I have seen it that is different approach...there you are calling database everytime but here the appraoch is different....check one more thing list.InnerHtml has any value during 2nd time?

Comment: That means it is working corerctly...Debug further in for loop and check??

Comment: you are still referring ViewState...thats why it is not working int index = (int)ViewState["Index"];

Comment: Why in Timer_tick you are calling GetDataForTable1.....Remove that method call and try again

Comment: if you want, i cam mail you the code for both the form.  i want the same functionality on `TimerTest.aspx` form. IF ok give me ur email id. the only difference is that there are `3` platform in `timertest` form. that's y the whole issue is

Comment: I am sorry but I cannot share my email Id.I will try my best to help you within this forum....you won't get complete code as working from fellow SO user...you have to take my example and change your code to fit your requirement......still you are facing issue then post a new question with updated code.....explaning new issue which you are facing.At this moment this is best I could do..from the given problem in question.my solution should work but you have some additional requirement which is not mentioned in question which makes it difficult for me to answer or provide appropriate solution.

Comment: One more suggestion never put your IP address in public forum....delete those comments with IP address

Comment: Deleted that. I guess you got the hint for what I m looking for. I will cross verify and check what's going wrong

Answer (score 0):

You can use database paging with oracle's `ROW_NUMBER` function:

```
string sql = @"
  select col1, col2, ...
  from (
      select col1, col2, ...,
      row_number()
      over (order by OrderColumn asc) rn
      from TableName
  )
  where rn between 3 and 4
";
```

Now you just have to parametrize the last min-row value, for example in session.

Comment: I am showing that data in a html table, so how can I show that using paging ?

Comment: @coder: why don't you use a web-databound control like `Repeater` or `GridView` which is rendered as Html-Table? You could make above method a WebMethod to load it from clienside to an existin html table.

Comment: but I don't want any paging. only simple HTML table just to show the data. have a look at the updated question

Comment: actually, I have done that by using `session`. but now my logic is changed so I dont want to use `session` now. If you want, i can show you the code